# Did Tolkien indicate that any adult male Elves have short hair?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

@Taylor17387 asked [Do male elves have long or short hair?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33693/do-male-elves-have-long-or-short-hair) regarding Tolkien's male Elves. The question and its answers focus on examples of male Elves with **long hair**. I want to ask about the converse:

**Does Tolkien write explicitly about any adult male Elves having short hair?** Hair short due to illness, or as part of the torment of Elvish prisoners does not count: I am looking for intentional hairstyles.

Answer (score 1):

I remember a Tolkien discussion in one of the History of Middle-Earth books about the royal family of the Noldor in which Tolkien describes the hairstyles of several, and gave the impression that some of them had highly individual hairstyles.

Thus there might not have been a single Elven male hairstyle worn by all male Elves everywhere and at every time.

So either:

One) Possibly there was a large degree of variation in variation in hair style and length.

or:

Two)  All Elf males wore the same hairstyle, except for the highly individualistic princes of the Noldorin royal family, which is why their distinctive hair styles were remembered.

Comment: I understand that Elves are big on individualism (e.g., the uniqueness of Elvish names—with that one exception)… but have any of them been described explicitly as having short hair?

Comment: Individual doesn't mean 'short'. It just means 'not the same'.

Comment: This answer can be improved by including the quote from HoMe you refer to, provided that it does indeed indicate short hair.